# What is the best neural network model to classify an x(t) signal according two classes?

Tags: neural-networks, classification

I am a beginner in AI methods. I have a collection of x(t) data, where x are some signal amplitudes and t is a time. My testing data are divided into two classes, say those from good and bad experimental samples. I need to classify the signals from unknown samples as good or bad according to their similarity to these two classes. What kind of a neural network is the best in this case? Could you recommend me some example in the literature where such a problem is considered?

Comment: RNN is the usual NN in case of variable length sequences as temporal ones.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Thank you.